# Lanczos Interpolation in Python with 2D images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, downsampling

I try to rescale 2D images (greyscale).
The image size is 256x256 and the desired output is 224x224.
The pixel values range from 0 to 1300.

I tried 2 approaches to rescale them with Lanczos Interpolation:

First using PIL Image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

array = np.random.randint(0, 1300, size=(10, 256, 256))
array[0] = Image.fromarray(array[0]).resize(size=(224, 224), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
```

resulting in the error message: `ValueError: image has wrong mode`

And then CV2:

```
array[0] = cv2.resize(array[0], dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

resulting in the error message: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224) into shape (256,256)`

How to do it properly?

Comment: Now it should be a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: Just a suspicion (it's been some time since I worked with ```opencv```). Constants in ```cv2``` are denoted slightly differently when you work with ```python``` Vs it's native ```c```. I would double check - whether this is really the name of the constant in ```python``` (I don't think it is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, you are resizing a 256x256 image to 224x224, then assigning it back into a slice of the original array. This slice still has size 256x256, so NumPy doesn't know how to do the data copy.

Instead, create a new output array of the right sizes:

```py
array = np.random.randint(0, 1300, size=(10, 256, 256))
newarray = np.zeros((10, 224, 224))
newarray[0] = cv2.resize(array[0], dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the PIL part, you have a few issues.

Firstly, you need to check the `dtype` of things you create! You create an array of `np.int64` when you use `np.random()` like that. As you know your data only maxes out at 1300, an unsigned 16-bit is preferable:

```
array = np.random.randint(0, 1300, size=(10, 256, 256), dtype=np.uint16)
```

Secondly, when you create a PIL Image from the Numpy array, you need to tell PIL the mode - greyscale or Lightness here:

```
array[0] = Image.fromarray(array[0], 'L')
```

Thirdly, you are trying to stuff the newly created PIL Image back into a Numpy array - don't do that:

```
newVariable = Image.fromarray(...).resize()
```